# In Sphinx, when using sphinx.ext.autosummary, how do I exclude base class members?

Tags: python-sphinx, jupyterbook, autosummary

I am using Sphinx to document a code base docString; in python. I have code like this -

```
class foo(np.ndarray):
    def foo_func():
      pass

class bar(foo):
    def bar_func():
       pass
```

When using sphinx.ext.autosummary to document the code base, in **bar**, how do I prevent inherited members from **foo** from showing?